# How do you run a jQuery function back-to-back, waiting for the first to complete?

Tags: jquery, callback, jquery-callback

I know I need a callback to solve this problem, but I just can't get it right.  I've tried a few different solutions, but I'll save you from having to look at my attempts.  Instead, I'll just show what I'm trying to accomplish.

```
theCodeToRun('123', '1');
//Wait for it to complete...
theCodeToRun('123', '0');

function theCodeToRun(myID, exitEarly){
    //Do some stuff (using myID)
    if(exitEarly == 1){
        return false; //Exit
    }
    //Do some more stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the second call inside of the callback passed to the first.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do in `theCodeToRun`? javascript is executed in single thread, so if no async-stuff in `theCodeToRun`, you do not need any callback. Otherwise, you can modify your code like this:

```
function theCodeToRun(func, flag, callback){
    if(flag){
        callbck();
    }
    func(callback);
}
```

You would be confused why `callback` is passed as parameter to `func`. Ok, in this case, we assume `func` is a routine do some async jobs, like making `ajax` calls. You need pass the `callback` to it to let `func` execute your callback once its job done.